# Why MAX always returns a row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, max

When running `SELECT MAX(col) FROM MY_TABLE` I still get a single row with `NULL` value even though `MY_TABLE` has no records in it. Comparing to `SELECT col FROM MY_TABLE` I would get zero row, why `MAX` behaves like that? Are there more like `MAX` that return a row anyway and what are they called? Besides using `MAX`, is there another example you can write a query to return a row with `NULL` values even though the condition in the `WHERE` clause does not meet (or when the table has no records)?

Comment: `MAX` returns a single value. It's the  `SELECT` query that *always* returns rows unless they are filtered out by a `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause

Comment: Did you consider looking at the documentation for [`MAX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? And then look at what section of the documentation it's in?

Comment: `Besides using MAX, is there another example ...` all aggregate queries at least. You asked for an aggregate calculation of a result set. It doesn't matter what the result set contains, `SELECT` must return results for the aggregates you asked.

Comment: As for the actual `why` I'm pretty sure there are several hundred academic papers, conference publications and SQL committee minutes debating the behavior of aggregates going back all the way to the early 80s if not 70s. This is definitely *NOT* a simple question - should an aggregate operation on an empty set return an empty set or not? How does that play with other operations? What were the pros and cons? And did some IBM business group release a quirky language despite CJ Date's objections?

Comment: BTW SQL *is* a quirky language that had nothing to do with the relational model. Some business group in IBM created a query language for business people at the same time another group developed the Relational model and the first relational databases. And then some product manager decided to put SQL on top of the relational databases despite the objections of CJ Date and the rest of the team that developed the Relational model.

Comment: Thanks. I am most interested in the why. Feel free to answer below if you want.

Comment: @user1589188 I answered that - most likely bad luck. Or well-reasoned discussions and arguments spanning decades. This simply can't be answered in a single SO question, except perhaps by the people that were actually involved in SQL's history. This is computational archeology

Comment: It is interesting that you assume it should return an empty set, but it could also throw an error. Because in many ways it is like a division by zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is called aggregation. `MAX` is an aggregation function, as are `MIN`, `SUM`, `COUNT`, `AVG`, etc. Aggregation functions lead to exactly one result row, unless you specify a `GROUP BY` clause or a `HAVING` clause.

A `GROUP BY` results in one or more rows, as it says "Give me an aggegation result per ___", e.g. "Give me the number of employees and the highest salary per department" which would result in one row per department.

The `HAVING` clause is like a `WHERE` clause on the aggragation result. In the given example you could add "but only for departments with at least ten employees" for instance.

Hence, if you don't want a result row in case there is no value in col (i.e. there exists no maximum value), add a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT MAX(col) FROM my_table HAVING MAX(col) IS NOT NULL;
```

Here is the SQL Server documentation on aggregation functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

**EDIT:**

As to whether there exist means to return nulls instead of no row in case of no data matching the `WHERE` clause: The `WHERE` clause eliminates the rows from the result, so we must find ways to get around this. One is outer joins, another is unioned queries and there may be other methods, too.

An example:

```
select dept_id, dept_name from departments where boss = 'Mr. X';
```

would return no row, if there isn't any department where the boss is Mr. X.

But we get null rows when outer joining tables:

```
select d.dept_id, d.dept_name 
from (select 1) dummy
left outer join departments d on boss = 'Mr. X';
```

Or we combine two queries, one for the match and one for no match:

```
select dept_id, dept_name from departments where boss = 'Mr. X'
union all
select null, null where not exists (select * from departments where boss = 'Mr. X');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess I asked 3 questions originally and you answered 2 of them and your content is more fit on SO, so I am picking yours as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not trying to answer why returning a row with NULL is the right way to do it. After all, NULL in SQL is a pretty bad idea itself, [criticised by both Codd and Date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Criticisms). This is trying to explain why finding an answer about `Why` is difficult and probably unsatisfactory

**UPDATE**

The Computer History Museum collects the very interviews that could answer this question. [There are interviews from Date, Chamberlin, Stonebraker](https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/oralhistories/?s=date) and more. I'd start searching there for answers - it's definitely more interesting than trying to find papers.

**Why? It all started ....**

It's hard to answer `why` and there may not be a logical explanation at all. There may be hundreds of academic papers, conference publications and ANSI SQL design committee meetings discussing how to handle analytic operations over empty sets.

Or it could be just bad luck. Perhaps it was an IBM sales manager deciding to put a quirky language on top of a database without thinking through the consequences. Which ... it probably was.

SQL is that quirky language that had nothing to do with the relational model. Some business group in IBM created a query language for business people at the same time another group developed the Relational model and the first relational databases. And then some product manager decided to marry both products and put SQL on top of the relational databases despite the objections of [CJ Date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_J._Date) and the rest of the team that developed the Relational model.

There was another *well designed query language* at the time, [QUEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUEL_query_languages) created by [Michael StoneBraker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Stonebraker), the creator of Ingres and PostgresQL, and a data legend equal to CJ Date. That language was built on top of the relational model from the start. Unfortunately, Ingres wasn't very reliable (you could lose data if you didn't shut down properly) and flopped, even though for a time it was bigger than Oracle.

**Wait, it gets worse**

At some point, some IBM employees in the SQL committee actually tried to standardize a specific order in equality comparisons : `number = field`, eg `3 = Id`. This would make it easier to write a SQL parser as there was no way to mistake this with an assignment. C and C++ developers may recognize this pattern. Needless to say the IBM researchers in the committee weren't happy.

So perhaps the behavior we have now came from vendors' implementation difficulties that led to compromises in the standard.

**How I know?**

I was lucky enough to attend lectures [by one of them, Hugh Darwen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_Darwen). CJ Date and Hugh Darwen even published [The Third Manifesto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Third_Manifesto) about those quirks and the problems reconciling object databases and relational-through-SQL databases.

Problems we still face today as once again, the industry as a whole went the wrong way. Just think about all the SO questions from people trying to use JOINs with EF Core

Comment: Very great background information! Its good to have you as an active member here to help ignorance people like me. I was astounded to find this aggregation functions behaviour when comparing to normal select, hence I was interested to know why the difference. But I wasn't to much asking about the story behind, I was interested to know if there can be any logical explanation why it has to behave differently to normal select queries.

Comment: @user1589188 turns out Computer History Museum [has interviews from Date, Chamberlan, Stonebraker](https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/oralhistories/?s=codd). I'll go through them when I have the time because reading papers is too much work

Answer (score 0):

> why MAX behaves like that

Because that's what the documentation, [MAX (Transact-SQL) - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks), says it does:

> #### Remarks
>
> MAX ignores any null values.
>
> **MAX returns NULL when there is no row to select.**
>
> For character columns, MAX finds the highest value in the collating sequence.
>
> MAX is a deterministic function when used without the OVER and ORDER BY clauses. It is nondeterministic when specified with the OVER and ORDER BY clauses. For more information, see Deterministic and Nondeterministic Functions.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Thanks, but you just restated what I wrote about the behaviour, you didn't answer any one of my questions.

Comment: I didn't restate, I quoted the documentation, @user1589188 . You asked *why* is works like that, and it works like that because that's the intention. That's what the documentation says it does. If it didn't behave like how the documentation did, that would be a major concern.

Comment: I don't know. Did you answer everything with "by design"?

Comment: @user1589188 the question you asked has no easy answer, in fact it's based on a pretty bad concept, NULL for three-valued logic. The actual `why` happened 30-40 years ago. A relational researcher may be able to answer this, simply because she or he happened to read the relevant publications decades ago, but those don't use SO. We can only come up with justifications, like `why would returning an empty set be worse?`.

Comment: If you are really asking the "why was SQL decided to work this way" 30-40 years ago, then what you are asking isn't even specific to SQL Server, @user1589188 .  You *might* get some insight on [dba.se], as it's more focused on the *why* databases work the way they do, but still, I'm not even sure it meets that focus. You're more likely hoping that someone like Joe Celko stumbles on your question and goes on one of his huge ISO Standards rants about why it works the way it does, and that months have a day 0, and years a month 0; just hope Jeff Modem doesn't see it! But I digress (kek).

Comment: Thanks again for the insight. I was astounded to find this aggregation functions behaviour when comparing to normal select, hence I was interested to know why the difference. But I wasn't to much interested into knowing "who" or "how" someone designed it like that, I just want to see if someone can explain "why" this makes sense.

Comment: Joe Celko would say "WHO CARES if it's proper relational theory, you must confuse by with Codd. It's the ISO STANDARD!". Which, in this case, is probably not a bad answer